# Compose Material 3 SearchBar window insets

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to use [`SystemBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#SearchBar(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.SearchBarColors,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1)) from Compose Material 3 in an edge-to-edge activity (I use [`enableEdgeToEdge()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).enableEdgeToEdge(androidx.activity.SystemBarStyle,androidx.activity.SystemBarStyle))).

I want the `SearchBar` to cover the whole screen with its surface when it is active, including the area under  the system bars, but I don't want its input field, its icons, or its content to be obscured by the system bars.

I expected `windowInsets` parameter to do exactly this when set to `WindowInsets.systemBars`, but it doesn't (it is actually already set to `WindowInsets.systemBars` by default).

What I want (trailing icons are not obscured by the navigation bar, but the surface of the `SearchBar` still fills the area under the navigation bar):
[image: SearchBar with trailing icons not obscured by the navigation bar]

What I get (the last trailing icon is obscured by the navigation bar):
[image: SearchBar with the last trailing icon is obscured by the navigation bar]

I could use `Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.systemBars)` but then the surface of the `SearchBar` won't fill the area under the system bars.

Answer (score 0):

For now I ended up manually adding window insets paddings to starts and ends of leading/trailing icons and the content and animating them. This looks almost perfect if you use the same animation spec as `SearchBar` does ("almost" because when I rotate the screen the paddings are also animated to push the contents from under the system bars instead of applying instantly). But if there is a better way, I'm still looking for it.